# Can I set a class member variable to the result of a class function?

Tags: c++

I have two functions in a `Vector` class, `x()` and `y()` that return the corresponding component from the vector. I want to be able to access the component using a member variable instead (or as well).

Previously I made `x` and `y` pointers that point directly into the array of components, `data` - but this isn't a good solution because someone could change the pointer, right? And it would need to be dereferenced every time it is used.

I cannot use a union due to how my classes are structured.

Currently my idea is to have the member variables `x` and `y` return the result of functions `x()` and `y()`. Is this a feasible solution?

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Vec2 : public VecBase<T, 2>
{
public:
    T& x = x();     //Doesn't work but is what I'm trying to achieve
    T& y = y();

    T& x() const { return data[0]; }
    T& y() const { return data[1]; }
}
```

EDIT: Should have made it more obvious - `VecBase` is a variable sized vector (vector2, vector3, etc.). `Vec2` adds `x` and `y` when the size is 2 to make accessing the components easier. It's hard to show without pasting all the code. Ha.

The outcome I want is to basically be able to access the components of the vector easily like so:

```cpp
Vec2<int> vector;
vector.x = 20;
vector.y = 40;
```

The functions `x()` and `y()` aren't necessary in the solution.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Unfortunately, C++ does not work this way. At least not without a massive amount of overloading and various other things that only create confusion and results in extremely convoluted code. Don't try to make C++ work like some other programming language. A class method is a class method. A class member is a class member. They don't really want to be each other.

Comment: Is it necessary to save it in an `std::vector` as well? Another comment on how you want to access the variables, are you sure you don't want to use a `get`- and `set`-function? In my eyes, please correct me, this would violently break the paradigm of data encapsulation.

Comment: Don't use references here, you're wasting memory for syntax sugar. It's a bad idea. Instead, do `T x, y;` and overload `operator[]` for array-like access.

Comment: @skratchi.at The base class ```VecBase``` allows for a variable sized vector (vector2, vector3, etc.) The ```Vec2``` class extends the functionality of that by allowing easy access through ```.x``` and ```.y``` when the number of components is 2 - that's the plan at least.

Comment: Aside: `T& x() const` is rather suspicious. Why can you modify part of a `const Vec2`? prefer `const T& x() const; T& x();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your reference member approach can work:

```
template <typename T>
class Vec2 : public VecBase<T, 2>
{
public:
    Vec2() : x(this->data[0]), y(this->data[1]) {}

    T& x;
    T& y;
};
```

However, now you have a user-defined constructor. Plus there's still going to be a dereference under the bonnet. Personally I'd avoid this over-complication entirely, if possible.

Although I understand that you want to implement the guts of it all in a generic way, and that your base can't "automatically" name the members in a nice mathsy way, consider whether you really need this. Why not just a couple of `Vec2`, `Vec3` types that literally just have direct members in them? Do you really need anything more?

Having `T` as a template parameter is a good idea though.

Comment: Well that could work! Thanks. The reason I have a base class is because there's going to be more behaviour (normalisation, dot product, cross product, operator overloading) etc. and I am trying to avoid re-writing functions in multiple classes that are only slightly different.

Comment: @Davinatoratoe Don't those operations have to be different for different orders anyway?

Comment: No, I have most of them working in any order so far :)

Answer (score 1):

> I want to be able to access the component using a member variable

Then simply use a `struct` (or `class` with `public` members):

```
template <typename T>
struct Vector
{ 
    T x;
    T y;
};

Vector<int> v;
v.x = 42;
v.y = data[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve almost what you want *without* the reference members. You can assign to the result of `x()`.

```
Vec2<int> vector;
vector.x() = 20;
vector.y() = 40;
```

Note that you shouldn't allow modifying through a `const Vec2`, so overload `x` and `y` based on the const qualification.

```
template <typename T>
class Vec2 : public VecBase<T, 2>
{
public:
    const T& x() const { return data[0]; }
    const T& y() const { return data[1]; }

    T& x() { return data[0]; }
    T& y() { return data[1]; }
};
```

Comment: Yeah, this is for an assignment that requires accessing the components via a variable, not a function. :( I'd love to do it that way if I could haha